# Parsing for keyword and finding related line in array

Tags: python, parsing

I am using python 3.3 and trying to parse for keyword "hypothetical" of which there are multiple occurances of in the file which is arranged as a single column array.

Following this I need to go 9 lines back up the array and print that line

Here is what I have so far:

```
#Opening the file
file = open('filename.txt')
print file.read()

#finding 'hypothetical'
searchfile = open('filename.txt' , 'r')
for line in searchfile:
    if "hypothetical" in line: print line

#finding 'Hypothetical'
searchfile2 = open('filename.txt' , 'r')
for line in searchfile2:
    if "Hypothetical" in line: print line
```

This finds and prints the lines containing "hypothetical" however I have no idea how to continue to find the other line. It must only happen when the keyword is found in the line.

Comment: a desired output for a given input would be nice

Comment: I wonder how `print line` can work in Python 3.3 :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first store your file in a cache array, then look through the cache again:

```
cache = []    
for line in searchfile:
    cache.append(line)
    if "hypothetical" in cache[line].lower():
        print(cache[-9])
```

Comment: Would it be possible to get the output as a .txt notepad file?

Comment: to write as .txt file, first create a results array of the lines you want to write. then use f = open("filename.txt", "w") and f.writelines(results)

Comment: What if there is an occurance of  "hypothetical" between lines 1 and 9?

Comment: if there is an occurance in the last 9, it will show up in the next 1-9 iterations of the loop

Answer (score 2):

If you potentially need to go back 9 lines the easiest solution is to put every line in a circular buffer with 9 elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a double-ended queue and a regular expression

```
import collections as co
import itertools as it
import re

pattern = re.compile(r'[Hh]ypothetical')
with open('filename.txt' , 'r') as searchfile:
    q = co.deque(it.islice(map(lambda x: x.rstrip('\n'), searchfile), 9), 9)
    for line in searchfile:
        if pattern.search(line):
            print(q[0])
        q.append(line.rstrip('\n'))
```

which, for example, with an input file of

```
1
2
3
4
Hypothetical A
6
7
8
9
hypothetical B
Hypothetical C
12
13
hypothetical D
15
```

produces

```
1
2
Hypothetical A
```

As you can see there are no special cases in the code to account for the first 9 lines (I assume there would be no lookup if there is a match in those, since there would not be enough lines to go back up by).

Comment: There are some strange, possibly-advanced Pythony things going on there. Could you break down some of the syntax for novice Python users familiar with other languages?